# Trouble creating an AudioQueueBufferRef in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, audiotoolbox

```
ringBuffers = [AudioQueueBufferRef](repeating: AudioQueueBufferRef(), count:inflightBuffersCount)
```

says `init() is unavailable: use 'nil' literal`

but if it is

```
ringBuffers = [AudioQueueBufferRef](repeating: nil, count: inflightBuffersCount)
```

it says

```
main.swift:152:29: Expression type '[AudioQueueBufferRef]' is ambiguous without more context
```

if it is

```
var ringBuffers = [AudioQueueBufferRef!](repeating:nil, count:3)
let status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(inQueue!, bufferSize, &ringBuffers[0])
print("\(status.description)")
```

prints

```
vm_map failed: 0x4 ((os/kern) invalid argument)
4
```

I think assigning `nil` is not right

Stream description I have used is

```
let inFormat = AudioStreamBasicDescription(
      mSampleRate:        Double(sampleRate),
      mFormatID:          kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
      mFormatFlags:       kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsBigEndian | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsSignedInteger | kLinearPCMFormatFlagIsPacked,
      mBytesPerPacket:    UInt32(numChannels * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size),
      mFramesPerPacket:   1,
      mBytesPerFrame:     UInt32(numChannels * MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size),
      mChannelsPerFrame:  UInt32(numChannels),
      mBitsPerChannel:    UInt32(8 * (MemoryLayout<UInt16>.size)),
      mReserved:          UInt32(0)
)
AudioQueueNewOutput(&inFormat, AQOutputCallback, &player, nil, nil, 0, &inQueue)
```

Answer (score 0):

You got this wrong ;) You don't need to allocate *anything* at all; the buffer will be created by the [`AudioQueueAllocateBuffer`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiotoolbox/1502248-audioqueueallocatebuffer) function you are calling.

For instance:

```
var buffer: AudioQueueBufferRef? = nil
let status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(inQueue!, bufferSize, &buffer)
```

Comment: swift says `nil cannot be assigned to AudioQueueBufferRef` it suggests me to replace with `AudioQueueBufferRef?`. but still `status = AudioQueueAllocateBuffer(outputQueue, UInt32(totalSize), &buffer)` is `4` with runtime error `vm_map failed: 0x4 ((os/kern) invalid argument)`

Comment: @neckTwi Please check your remaining arguments as well.